# Inverting a sparse Matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse

I have a sparse, square, symmetric matrix with the following structure:
(Let's say the size of the matrix is N x N)

[image]

Here, the area under the blue stripes is the non-zero elements. Could someone tell me if there is a algorithm to invert this kind of matrix that is simple yet more efficient than Gaussian elimination and LU decomposition? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, it is less about programming, more about Maths or Numerics.

Comment: Could you tell me a more appropriate forum to address this kind of question? Thanks.

Comment: mathoverflow or math.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

Cholesky factorization is faster, O(n²). Or some specialized multi-band solvers, if you know the number of non-zero off-diagonals.

You can also apply iterative methods, maybe with preconditioning, it depends on your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of sparse solvers. This can easily be solved using [libeigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicSparseSystems.html). What solver you choose is really going to depend on the properties of the sparse matrix besides the structure. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does not answer the question. He still has to choose an algorithm from Eigen.